# Route gameserver traffic through cloudflare?

Tags: proxy, denial-of-service

I use cloudflare for my website and we have a gameserver I was wondering if it is possible to route traffic through cloudflare.

This recently sprung into my head when I realized that I could route Shoutcast through another of cloudflares port (8080) which does not do any performance enhancing or anything it just acts as a reverse proxy and stops DDoS.

I then tried by setting up a subdomain with my gameserver IP cloudflared and then pinged the IP and Port. It seems to have connections but when actually connecting via the game it doesnt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually get DDoS attacks on your server?

Answer (score 4):

Cloudflare mitigates DDoS attacks by performing distributed caching.

One does not simply cache a gameserver.